# Mosaic plot and text values

Tags: r, mosaic-plot

I created structable from Titanic dataset and used mosaic function for it. Everything worked great, hovewer I also wanted to label each box from mosaic plot with quantity of titanic passangers given their Class, Survival and Sex. As it turns out, I am not able to do that. I know I need to use labeling_cells to achive that, hovewer i am not able to use it (and i wan't able to find any example) in combination with stuctable and below code.

```
library("vcd")
struct <- structable(~ Class + Survived + Sex, data = Titanic)
mosaic(struct, data = Titanic, shade = TRUE, direction = "v")
```

Answer (score 2):

Fixed in upstream in vcd 1.4-4, but note that you can simply use

```
mosaic(struct, labeling = labeling_values)
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, then the last example in `?labeling_cells` is pretty close to what you want to do. Using your example, the `labeling_cells()` can be added afterwards provided that the viewport tree is not `pop`ped. The only aspect that is somewhat awkward is that the `struct` object has to be a regular table again for the labeling. I have to ask David, the main author, whether this could be handled automatically.

```
mosaic(struct, shade = TRUE, direction = "v", pop = FALSE)
labeling_cells(text = as.table(struct), margin = 0)(as.table(struct))
```

[image: mosaic labeling cells]